# Extended class running from super via same method (Java)

Tags: java, overriding, extends

The title is pretty confusing I know but I could not think of another way of wording it.

So, what I am trying to achieve: I have seen some java programs have a load of subclasses that have a method in their super class, and they all run when the supers method is called.
What I am trying to do is make ever single child class of Synchroniser run their own RunAll method when I call the Synchroniser.RunAll method.

I have tried multiple things and I've googled a lot but what I've found doesn't work for me.

Here is what I have: The SUPER class

```
public class Synchroniser 
{
    public Synchroniser()
    {
        RunAll();
    }

    protected void RunAll()
    {
        System.out.println("RunAll");
    }
}
```

The SUBCLASS:

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

public class ArrayList extends Synchroniser
{
    public ArrayList()
    {

    }

    public static void Keybind(Info info)
    {
        info.Toggle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void RunAll()
    {
        System.out.println("Ran ArrayList");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Call the superclass method from the subclass?

Comment: What is it you are expecting/want to happen?

Comment: Can you post the code you have to call the RunAll method? What do you see and what do you expect?

Comment: its not clear what youre trying to do here...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for the **observer pattern**. Have you googled that? Or maybe **template method**?

Your code doesn't match (which is probably why it doesn't work), but your description of the problem does.

Comment: I will google the observer pattern now but could you quickly explain to me why my code doesn't match? It uses the same method name and visibility which is how I thought it worked.

Comment: @user1363526 also look up template method pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Bases on your latest comment, @Luchian was the right one. Here is a simple example applied to your use case - ps: not a good idea to use existing JDK classes as names for your own classes (ArrayList):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList child1 = new ArrayList(1);
        ArrayList child2 = new ArrayList(2);
        Synchronizer sync = new Synchronizer(); //prints RunAll in Parent
        sync.addListener(child1);
        sync.addListener(child2);
        sync.runAll(); //prints RunAll in Parent, in Child 1 and in Child 2
    }

    public static interface RunAll {

        void runAll();
    }

    public static class Synchronizer implements RunAll {

        List<RunAll> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<RunAll>();

        public Synchronizer() {
            runAll();
        }

        public void addListener(RunAll l) {
            listeners.add(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void runAll() {
            System.out.println("RunAll in Parent");
            for (RunAll l : listeners) {
                l.runAll();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayList implements RunAll {
        private final int i;

        private ArrayList(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void runAll() {
            System.out.println("RunAll in Child " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is actually the exact opposite that I am trying to achieve however I think I am capable of using the information you have given me and swapping it around. Thanks!

Comment: Basically I have a lot of child classes all with the exact same format as the ArrayList class, I need every single child class to run a method once their super class tells them to. I'm trying to avoid doing individual callings since I have a lot of child classes

Comment: Aaaah. So what you say is that `aSynchronizer.runAll()` should trigger the `runAll()` method of all the instances of subclasses of Synchronizer?

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to achieve, do you have any advise on how I could do this? I've tried to reverse your original method however I'm not particularly being successful.

Comment: @user1363526 see my edit - I think this is what you asked for.